# Boot from external hard disk

Tags: boot, hard-drive, mysql, data-recovery, lamp

I recently upgraded hard drive with ubuntu/windows to ssd with ubuntu.
I had backup of databases from mysql but the files got corrupted somehow and I can't import them.
Now, I want to boot from hard drive (that I am using as external hard disk with usb) so that I can re-export the databases from phpmyadmin.

Or is there anyway I can copy some files of phpmyadmin of old drive to ssd and recover databases?
I know the files are in /op/lampp/var/mysql but replacing those files didn't work.
I hope I could get some help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to boot from your previous hard drive with Ubuntu/Windows?  In this case, enter the BIOS at boot and select the right disk to boot from.

Comment: Which version of MySQL were you using on the hard drive? It may be possible to simply lift the original files and move them to a new data directory on the SSD, but only if the versions of MySQL are very close.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen I converted my previous hard drive into external hard drive. The system doesn't seem to recognize it as bootable drive now. Others say I will have to plug it directly as hard drive to boot from it again, which I haven't been able to try because of lack of time. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @Matigo the version was 7.2. I will try it. Thank you.